# Removing a string it not followed by a table using a VBA macro in word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm facing a challenging request I need to solve using a VBA Macro in Word.

The document is a template that will grab some data in a DB upon generation. It contains multiple tables but I don't know how many and how many data will be in each table.

It looks like this:

[Sample initial state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poEzs.png)

The requirement is to be able to detect the strings that are not followed by a table and delete them.
Said differently when a string is followed by the table, it's all good. When a string is followed by another string, it should be deleted.

The different strings are known, I'm guessing this would help.

After the macro run, my previous sample should look like this:

[Sample expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXNBo.png)

I know it looks bit harsh but I don't even know where to start :(

I've looked at macro searching for a text but I wasn't able to find something like
IF stringA is followed by a table then do nothing if not then delete.

Any help of the community would be very much appreciated!

Thanks
Julien

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started:

```
Sub FindAndDelete()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ActiveDocument.Content
    With rng
        With .Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Text = "Text to find"
        End With
        Do While .Find.Execute
            If .Next(wdParagraph).Tables.Count = 0 Then
                .Next(wdParagraph).Delete
            End If
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much!

I was able to make it work by slightly modifying it as the proposed code was deleting the string followed by the table:

```
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ActiveDocument.Content
    With rng
        With .Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Text = "This is my table C"
        End With
        Do While .Find.Execute
            If .Next(wdParagraph).Tables.Count = 0 Then
                .Delete
            End If
        Loop
    End With
```

my last step is to make the macro run only for a specific part of the document. I guess I need to work on the range. I'll give a try and post the result here.
Again thank you for helping pure newbies!

Answer (score 0):

So I had it working using the below code. I slightly modify the "while" loop so that it deletes the entire row rahter than just the word

```
Sub HeaderDelete()
'
' HeaderDelete Macro
'
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ActiveDocument.Content
    With rng
        With .Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Text = "This is my table A"
            
        End With
        
        Do While .Find.Execute
            If .Next(wdParagraph).Tables.Count = 0 Then
            Selection.HomeKey wdLine
            Selection.EndKey wdLine, wdExtend
            Selection.Delete
            End If
             
        Loop
      
        With .Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Text = "This is my table B"
            
        End With
        Do While .Find.Execute
            If .Next(wdParagraph).Tables.Count = 0 Then
            Selection.HomeKey wdLine
            SelectionS.EndKey wdLine, wdExtend
            Selection.Delete
            End If
             
        Loop
    
        With .Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Text = "This is my table C"
        End With
        Do While .Find.Execute
            If .Next(wdParagraph).Tables.Count = 0 Then
            Selection.HomeKey wdLine
            SelectionS.EndKey wdLine, wdExtend
            Selection.Delete
            End If
             
        Loop
    
    End With

End Sub
```

The challenge is I have 50+ "this is my table X" and they may possibly change overtime...

I tried to find a solution which wouldn't be used on the ".Find" but more on "if there is a row not followed by a table then delete" but I wasn't successful so far.

On a side note I wanted to remove the table borders of all my tables and I found the below which works great!

```
  Dim doc As Document
  Dim tbl As Table

  Set doc = ActiveDocument
  For Each tbl In doc.Tables
                 With tbl.Borders
                    .InsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
                     .OutsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
                End With

  Next
```

Again, thanks a lot for helping VBA newbies!